# How to recursively work on input set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Work on sql server 2008 r2,Need help on recursively charge amount calculation process.want to write an sp,In my sp I need to calculate head sum base on parameter head and given amount:
Picture describe my db input set,from the input set I need to calculate total charge amount on given head,

[image]

My table script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testCharge](
    [Head] [int] NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [IsPercent] [bit] NULL,
    [Head Percent] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testCharge] ([Head], [Amount], [IsPercent], [Head Percent]) VALUES (100, CAST(10.000000 AS Decimal(18, 6)), 1, 103)
INSERT [dbo].[testCharge] ([Head], [Amount], [IsPercent], [Head Percent]) VALUES (101, CAST(10.000000 AS Decimal(18, 6)), 1, 102)
INSERT [dbo].[testCharge] ([Head], [Amount], [IsPercent], [Head Percent]) VALUES (102, CAST(50.000000 AS Decimal(18, 6)), 0, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[testCharge] ([Head], [Amount], [IsPercent], [Head Percent]) VALUES (103, CAST(20.000000 AS Decimal(18, 6)), 1, 101)
```

Used bellow syntax to retrieved values,Here problem is how to calculate on CTE.

```
DECLARE @HeadID INT = 103 ;
WITH    MyCTE
          AS ( 

          ---get base
                SELECT   Head ,
                        [Head Percent] ,
                        IsPercent ,
                        Amount
               FROM     testCharge
               WHERE    Head = @HeadID



               UNION ALL
               --get base related records
               SELECT   charge.Head ,
                        charge.[Head Percent] ,
                        charge.IsPercent ,
                        charge.Amount
               FROM     MyCTE cte
                        INNER JOIN testCharge charge ON cte.[Head Percent] = charge.Head

             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    MyCTE
```

**Suppose :**

```
for my inputset-1 my head parameter is Utility and given amount is 400 sp return 10

for my inputset-2 my head parameter is Wages and given amount is 800 sp return 11

for my inputset-3 my head parameter is Utility and given amount is 500 sp return 56.1
```

How to recursively work on input set.

**Note:** My input already in DB,No need to think about input set.

Comment: Show what you have tried ? throw some sample data.Use group by.if you want many column in final resultset.Use CTE

Comment: KumarHarsh,thanks for reply.i just need one result the charge amount like:picture sum field amount.I am new in CTE ,please provide some syntax.

Comment: ok good.one last query.what output u r expecting from your query.just draw it.

Comment: KumarHarsh,as i tell in my above comment,i need dynamic column calculatedAmount sum value.Please check the pic ,there are some rules,base on rules dynamic value generate,i just want sum of dynamic column value.

Comment: no it is not much clear .you need to explain how calculated value derive and from your sample data,what output you are expecting.forget about pic above.